# How do i check if the arrow keys are pressed in assembly 16 Bits bare bones

Tags: assembly, keyboard, ascii, x86-16, bios

I try to check if the arrow keys are pressed and i started with the up key but

```
cmp al, 48h ;if you press the up arrow
je  .up_pressed
```

nor

```
cmp al, 48  ;if you press the up arrow
je  .up_pressed
```

work, it is or 8 or none, and i cant find anything that works for me! does anyone know what the correct code is? it can be hexadecimal ascii or binary. (i need the left, right, down & up keys)

but these DO work:

```
cmp al, 13  ;if you press enter
je  .done

cmp al, 8       ;if you press backspace
je  .backspace
```

i do not get input via:

```
mov ah, 00h
int 16h
```

but:

```
cmd:
call newline
mov si, prompt
call    Print
mov di, input_buffer
mov al, 0
mov cx, 256
rep stosb
mov ax, input_buffer
mov di, input_buffer
;check for characters typed
.loop:
call    keyboard

cmp al, 13  ;if you press enter
je  .done

cmp al, 8       ;if you press backspace
je  .backspace

cmp al, 27  ;if you press ESC
je  .escape_pressed

cmp al, 48h ;if you press the up arrow
je  .up_pressed

jmp .character  ;otherwise just register a character

.up_pressed:
call newline
mov si, debug
call Print
jmp cmd

.backspace:     ;remove a character
mov ah, 0Eh
mov al, 8
int 10h
mov al, 32
int 10h
mov al, 8
int 10h
dec di
jmp .loop

.escape_pressed:
call newline
mov si, escape_pressed_message
call Print
jmp cmd

.character:     ;register a character
mov ah, 0Eh
int 10h
stosb
jmp .loop

.done:          ;start comparing input<->commands
mov ax, 0
stosb

call    newline ;but first make a new line

mov si, input_buffer
cmp BYTE [si], 0

je  cmd
```

there is a call to keyboard so here the keyboard code:

```
keyboard:
       pusha
       mov  ax, 0
       mov  ah, 10h
       int  16h
       mov  [.buffer], ax
       popa
       mov  ax, [.buffer]
       ret

       .buffer  dw  0
```

Comment: You forgot to show how you are getting the input. Anyway, use the appropriate table for your input method or check in a debugger what the actual values received are. PS: arrow keys don't have ascii code, chances are you are using the wrong input function.

Comment: Missing a [mcve]

Comment: `int16/00` returns [scan code](http://www.stanislavs.org/helppc/scan_codes.html) in `ah`, compare that to detect arrow keys since they don't have corresponding ascii code.

Comment: Jester: warning: byte value exceeds bounds (cmp al, 4800)

Comment: You know `al` is the low 8 bits of AX, right?  And that `4800` > `0xFF`?

Comment: The linked table includes the ascii code (`00` for arrow keys) so compare to `ax` or just use the top 8 bits when comparing with `ah`.

Comment: *"i do not get input via"* .. so HOW do you get it?

Comment: it does not work if i do cmp ax, 4800 ; it just does nothing

Comment: Ped7G, read the rest from cmd: ; there is a but: and there is much more code under that

Comment: `4800` is in hex. You should use `4800h`.

Comment: cmp ax, 4800h still does not work :(

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: What is wrong here?

Comment: The rest of code doesn't read keyboard in any known way to me. There is some `call    keyboard` (that code was not posted), and then you magically start to compare `al` for values. [MCVE] ?

Comment: look at the updated question

Comment: from the docs it looks like `int 16h,10h` is same thing as `int 16h,0` ... which makes me wonder, why don't you call rather the zero variant. Also the `mov ax,0` `mov ah,10h` is abundant, just do `mov ax,1000h` to set both ah+al, but ultimately the `int 16h` doesn't care about `al`, so just remove the `mov ax,0`. Also `pusha/popa` in this case is probably not needed, I think the BIOS will preserve other registers. But feel free to verify in debugger. But overall it's not clear why you don't receive scan code in `ah` plus zero in `al`, even your code should work like that.

Comment: i do not use a int 16h, please read the question correctly!

Comment: Do you need a freehand circle? The `int 16h` is right there in `keyboard` function.

Comment: Maybe \*you\* should read correctly your own question (and especially code)? :D Judging by the code you posted it looks like you sort of don't fully grasp x86 assembly basics, so going through your code since start in debugger step by step, and comparing that to the instruction reference guide, making sure you understand everything about each instruction may help a lot to better identify where you are, and what is not working as expected.

Comment: oh wow, maybe i was confused a bit! sorry for that. but i do understand it.. i just overlooked the int 16h, probably because i am now doing much with time and i wanted to debug it (i left it alone for 2 months)

Comment: It's not "bare metal" if you're making BIOS calls with `int xx`.  Your code depends on the legacy PC BIOS firmware to talk to the bare metal in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, simplify the code a bit. Pushing and popping here was quite useless.

```
keyboard:
    mov  ah, 00h
    int  16h
    mov  [.buffer], ax
    ret
    .buffer  dw  0
```

If there's no particular reason then don't use the 10h function on `int 16h`. Stick with the 00h function to retrieve a key from `int 16h`.

For the <kbd>up</kbd> key this function will give you a scancode in the `AH` register, so **that** is where your program needs to look:

```
cmp al, 27      ;if you press ESC
je  .escape_pressed

cmp AH, 48h     ;if you press the up arrow
je  .up_pressed

jmp .character  ;otherwise just register a character
```

### Important

Don't look for the <kbd>up</kbd> key by comparing the whole `AX` register!
You will not always recieve AX=4800h.

- When the <kbd>up</kbd> key on the numerical keypad was used, you will get AX=48E0h instead.
- When you combine the <kbd>up</kbd> key with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> (or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> you will get values like 4838h, 0008h, 8D00h, 48E0h, 9800h, 8DE0h respectively.

---

The other keys are:

```
cmp AH, 50h     ;if you press the down arrow
je  .down_pressed
cmp AH, 4Bh     ;if you press the left arrow
je  .left_pressed
cmp AH, 4Dh     ;if you press the right arrow
je  .right_pressed
```

Comment: To what end? For a simple "up" key just check if `AH=48h`. That will cover the usual arrow key and the one on the numerical keypad. You should not expect the user of your application to use any of those combinations I showed.